# How to make FB.api call

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I am using the FB JavaScript SDK and followed the FB tutorial exactly. I have added the login button, logged in with my FB account and am trying to make a very basic FB.api call but am not getting a proper response even after I login with facebook. Here's the code:

```
 <script>
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
     FB.init({
       appId      : '291660820848913',
       status     : true, 
       cookie     : true,
       xfbml      : true,
       oauth      : true,
     });

   FB.api('/me', function(response) {
     alert(response.name);
   });  

   };
   (function(d){
      var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
      d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));

 </script>
```

This gives me an alert that says "undefined". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What alert specifically? What does your error console report?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   FB.api('/me', function(response) {
     alert(response.name);
   });
```

This should only be done if you know the user is authenticated.  You should put a call to `FB.getLoginStatus()` prior to calling the `FB.api()`.

Comment: I tried that as well, but still was not able to make the FB.api call. any other possibilities?

Comment: Check your response stream coming back from Facebook when your browser makes the call.

Answer (score 3):

easily change the line

`js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";`

to this :

`js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're logged in before.

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  if (response.status=="connected") {
    console.log("You're loggued in");
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       alert(response.name);
      }); 
  } 
});
```

In this example, I'm forcing the login, but consider checking the status before (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to the event:

ie)

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    alert(response.name);
  });
});
```